# Is a pyramid considered axisymmetric? Why so?

Tags: applied-mechanics, mathematics, solid-mechanics, geometry

I read a source, I will not reference the source on this platform.

They stated a pyramid is axisymmetric. Can you explain why if yes?

Comment: If you look perpendicularly at each face what do you think?

Comment: If I look perpendicularly at each face? So for the 4 side faces, I will see a triangle for all of them. For the bottom side,I will see a square. Think of what exactly?

Comment: There was a reply yesterday paraphrasing,' the pyramid has no rotational symmetry, therefore not axis symmetric, however it is cyclic symmetric.'

Comment: A cone is axisymmetric.  A pyramid changes dimensions at different points of the compass.